# Why does a verify method return false value in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class MockitoSpyTest {

    @Spy
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList();

    @Test
    public void shouldAddItemsToListSuccessfully() {
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");

        verify(list, times(2)).add(anyString());

        System.out.println(verify(list).add("one")); // false
        verify(list).add("two");

        Assert.assertEquals(2, list.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share you code as formatted text, not an image

Comment: Try removing `verify(list, times(2)).add(anyString());`

Comment: @Turing85 the question is why ;-)

Comment: @shikida I imagine because the call-"events" were already consumed by `verify(list, times(2)).add(anyString());` and cannot be re-consumed by another `verify(...)`-call.

Comment: @Turing85: verify(list, times(2)).add(anyString()); also returns false

Comment: That's.... interesting.

Comment: Actually, looks like a bug in Mockito, because add() always return true, so it should be the  expected return from this method call.

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether this is a bug in Mockito. In fact, I am not sure whether the value returned by `verify(...)...` should be used at all. Semantically, it does not make much sense since we are not actually passing a parameter to the implementation, but want to verify that a matching call has happened in the past (i.e. during the when-action of the test).

Comment: I **definitively** think it is. When I run the debug here, sometimes, when the step by step takes enough time, the result is true instead of false. This is probably related to internal listeners that Mockito uses.

Answer (score 2):

I definitively think this is a Mockito bug.

In order to reproduce the bug, here's my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5164702379587769464L;

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        System.out.println("I am "+System.identityHashCode(this));
        boolean b = super.add(e);
        System.out.println("Returning "+b);
        return b;
    }

}
```

and

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class MockitoSpyTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldAddItemsToListSuccessfully() {
        
        List<String> originalList = new MyArrayList<>();
        
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(originalList));
        
        List<String> list = Mockito.spy(originalList);
        
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(list));
        
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        
        List<String> z = verify(list, times(2));
        
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(z));
        
        z.add(anyString());
        
        List<String> x = verify(list);
        
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(x));
        
        boolean y = x.add("one");
        
        System.out.println(y); //<<<<<<<<<
        
        boolean k = verify(list).add("two");
        
        System.out.println(k);

        Assert.assertEquals(2, list.size());
    }
}
```

If I run it using eclipse, the result I get is

```
1645624121
489070295
I am 489070295
Returning true
I am 489070295
Returning true
489070295
489070295
false
false
```

now, if I run the same thing in debug mode, step by step, here's the result I've got

```
1288108586
355649049
I am 355649049
Returning true
I am 355649049
Returning true
355649049
I am 355649049
Returning true
355649049
I am 355649049
Returning true
true <<<<<<
false
```

The expected result for the List.add() is always true, and it's known that Mockito copies the original object when you spy on it, so the expected result here is always true.

However, I can't tell if this is related to the internal listeners that Mockito uses or if the debug mechanism in Eclipse is affecting how Mockito intercepts the method calls.

So my suggestion here is that you join Mockito group -- https://groups.google.com/g/mockito -- and tell their team about this issue.

UPDATE - I've submitted already, myself.

Being a good citizen

```
Eclipse info
Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
Build id: 20210312-0638
```

JVM

```
java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=15.0.2+7-27
```

Mockito version

```
mockito-inline-3.11.2
mockito-core-3.11.2
byte-buddy-1.11.3
byte-buddy-agent-1.11.3
objenesis-3.2
```

JUnit version

```
plugins\org.junit_4.13.0.v20200204-1500.jar
plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v20180420-1519.jar
```

Comment: I used another Mockito version, the snippet is from MockHandlerImpl, if you'd like to look for the line there...

Answer (score 0):

It's an 'error' in Mockito, but another as you expect:

since verify alwas returns the mock/spy, the shown value is the return value of add("one"), that should always be true(see JavaDoc of ArrayList add), but

```
public Object handle(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    if (invocationContainerImpl.hasAnswersForStubbing()) {
        // stubbing voids with stubVoid() or doAnswer() style
        InvocationMatcher invocationMatcher = matchersBinder.bindMatchers(
                mockingProgress.getArgumentMatcherStorage(),
                invocation
        );
        invocationContainerImpl.setMethodForStubbing(invocationMatcher);
        return null;
    }
    VerificationMode verificationMode = mockingProgress.pullVerificationMode();

    InvocationMatcher invocationMatcher = matchersBinder.bindMatchers(
            mockingProgress.getArgumentMatcherStorage(),
            invocation
    );

    mockingProgress.validateState();

    // if verificationMode is not null then someone is doing verify()
    if (verificationMode != null) {
        // We need to check if verification was started on the correct mock
        // - see VerifyingWithAnExtraCallToADifferentMockTest (bug 138)
        if (((MockAwareVerificationMode) verificationMode).getMock() == invocation.getMock()) {
            VerificationDataImpl data = createVerificationData(invocationContainerImpl, invocationMatcher);
            verificationMode.verify(data);
--->>       return null;  // <<--- here we end up
        } else {
            // this means there is an invocation on a different mock. Re-adding verification mode
            // - see VerifyingWithAnExtraCallToADifferentMockTest (bug 138)
            mockingProgress.verificationStarted(verificationMode);
        }
    }

    // prepare invocation for stubbing
    invocationContainerImpl.setInvocationForPotentialStubbing(invocationMatcher);
    OngoingStubbingImpl<T> ongoingStubbing = new OngoingStubbingImpl<T>(invocationContainerImpl);
    mockingProgress.reportOngoingStubbing(ongoingStubbing);

    // look for existing answer for this invocation
    StubbedInvocationMatcher stubbedInvocation = invocationContainerImpl.findAnswerFor(invocation);

    if (stubbedInvocation != null) {
        stubbedInvocation.captureArgumentsFrom(invocation);
        return stubbedInvocation.answer(invocation);
    } else {
         Object ret = mockSettings.getDefaultAnswer().answer(invocation);

        // redo setting invocation for potential stubbing in case of partial
        // mocks / spies.
        // Without it, the real method inside 'when' might have delegated
        // to other self method and overwrite the intended stubbed method
        // with a different one. The reset is required to avoid runtime exception that validates return type with stubbed method signature.
        invocationContainerImpl.resetInvocationForPotentialStubbing(invocationMatcher);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Since the call is in verificationMode we land in an if where alwys null is returned and not the value of the invocation(which is true)

Later on Mockito notices that the return type is boolean and null not valid, so it takes the default value false.

But the intention in verifiying a call isn't really doing the call, so the return value is usually ignored.